# Encoding SAS data in ANSI format in Python

Tags: python, encoding, sas

I'm trying to import a 4 gb SAS data into python. Inside there are firms' information including names and other codes. However there seems to be some error with encoding.

I try to use the `read_sas` in `pandas` package. However when I use `encoding = "UTF-8"`, it gives me the error message: `"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 249: unexpected end of data"`

And I also try to specify `encoding = "mbcs"`, because when I use proc contents to check my sas file, it says the file is encoded in ANSI format. But the company names (which are the most important objects for me) shows characters like this `"Ã°Ââ€œâ€™Ã°Ââ€œÂªÃ°Ââ€œÂ¹Ã°Ââ€œÂ½Ã°Ââ€œÂª"`

Do you have any idea how should I solve the problem? Any possible solution is very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no "ANSI format" and Python 3 strings are Unicode. `mbcs` isn't the only multi-byte encoding or even a popular one. Windows uses UTF-16 LE. Try specifying one of the *other* Unicode encodings like `utf-16le`, `utf-16be` etc. Or remove `encoding` completely, in which case the text is treated as raw bytes

Comment: The raw bytes are useful too, because they may provide a hint to the actual encoding. The multi-byte encodings use NULL (0x00) in unused bytes. The combination of null and non-null characters could provide a hint about the actual encoding. UTF16 would use 2 or more bytes. UTF-32 always uses 4 bytes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the hint. I delete encode completely and there are some columns abnormal. One columns (column name) shows characters like `b'\xc3\xb0\xc2\x9d\xe2\x80\x98\xe2\x80\x99\xc3...`, others add `b''`, so for instance a column with url it becomes `b'bouncer.co.in'`. The latter I guess I could strip `b` and `''`, but for the first one, do you know what kind of encoding that is?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I also tried `utf-16le` and `utf-16be`, and I got the following error `'utf-16-be' codec can't decode byte 0x79 in position 6: truncated data`, i think this suppose starting from this position, encoding way change?

Comment: Check the actually codes.  Are you sure it is not using a single byte encoding? Trying to interpret a single byte encoding as it if was UTF-8 can yield that error message since some combinations of bytes are invalid in UTF-8, but for a single byte encoding any byte combination is valid.

Comment: @Tom Sorry I'm not familiar with the encoding check, can you point out how to see if it is using a single byte encoding? I could not find any articles on google

Comment: SAS data adds b'' to encode "best" as its guess for the column type.

Comment: Can you provide the following additional information:
Are you able to modify the sas datatypes using a sas source like base sas or sas eg?
Are you able to pip install a python package called saspy and connect to a sas instance in that way? It has native sas to dataframe functions.

Comment: @AdhdDatascientist Hi thank you for the reply. I have some problem with my sas license on my working computer, and I cannot open the sas file on a virtual desktop provided by the school because the data is too big. This is why I would like to open with python on my working computer. I can install saspy in python, but I'm not sure where should I connect. I read the saspy document, it seems I should connect to sas and operate, but I do not even have a sas that stores my data.

Comment: However, I do borrow my colleague's workstation to browse the sas dataset, and the last several lines contain weird letters even opening the dataset using sas directly. They are mostly company names originally in Japanese, Chinese, French (non english letter) So I guess it is a problem from the data supplier instead of my encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so based off the additional information you have provided, most of our solutions regarding pandas or read_sas aren't entirely applicable.

The root issue is likely the original data importing into sas based on:

> the last several lines contain weird letters even opening the dataset using sas directly.

From documentation, the sas default is latin1: [Link to default encode](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/nlsref/p1tktrbvawjqtzn180bw7al9wl5k.htm)

It may be possible to transcode the data if your workflow has the raw or stored the byte values:
[Transcode Overview](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/nlsref/n11rui69b5g2nzn100pefw2a54x4.htm).
You may also be able to force utf-8 on import or somewhere else:
[Sas Encodings](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/nlsref/n1r7pnb91iybs9n1hgvsj7q09srd.htm)

We can maybe help further, but you'll have to post some samples of the sas code / data.
All else fails you can try a proc export to csv.